# Excel left and right substring

Tags: excel, substring

I have text in a cell which starts with [ and ends in ] and I want to show the text between these two characters.

So far I have this:

```
    =LEFT(A2, SEARCH("]",A2)-1)
```

but it still shows as [1234. I just need to figure out how to remove the first [.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. If you know your string always starts with `[` and ends with `]` then you could use:

```
    =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"[",""),"]","")
```

If there may be text before [ and / or after ], then try:

```
    =MID(A2,FIND("[",A2)+1,FIND("]",A2)-FIND("[",A2)-1)
```

Comment: Excellent Olly thank you. The second one worked a treat.

Comment: I was trying to find something to say it has been answered but cannot see a check box anywhere. I will be posting another question soon as well - it will be an easy one for you Olly !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "strip" the first and the last character, independently of what they are, you can do this:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(RC[-1],LEN(RC[-1])-1),LEN(RC[-1])-2)
```

Comment: Or simplified to: `=MID(RC[-1],2,LEN(RC[-1])-2)`

Comment: Thank you Vityata